# WinRT Animation: Return rectangle properties to original states

Tags: animation, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am changing the appearance of two rectangles when one of them is tapped. The following code works fine on tap. But when I released the tap, the rectangles do not return to their original states.

What am I missing?

```
            <Storyboard x:Name="RectTapped">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectTop" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF43A047" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectBottom" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            </Storyboard>
```

The storyboard is triggered by `Behaviors`

```
   <Rectangle x:Name="rectBottom" Fill="#FF317434" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="42" RadiusY="6" RadiusX="6" StrokeThickness="0" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Width="320" Margin="0" Tapped="rectangle1_Tapped"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rectTop" Fill="#FF43A047" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="42" RadiusY="6" RadiusX="6" StrokeThickness="0" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Width="320" Margin="0,-9,0,0">
                            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                    <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource RectTapped}"/>
                                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

                        </Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use event **PointerPressed** for turn on your animation and **PointerReleased** for returning back

Answer (score 0):

You Can create an animation using Visual Studio Blend and then use the reverse function to reverse the animation to its original form and then you can simply call the individual animations.